# Getting the ID and inner text of the element (children) inside a div

Tags: javascript

I have **multiple** div's that represent some products, example below :

```
<div class="special" id="special">
    <a href="12v.html" class="special-link">
        <p class="special-img">
            <img src="img/25.png" alt="">
        </p>
        <h3><span id="pdctName">12v XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX</span></h3>
    </a>
    <p class="special-info">
        <span class="ribbon2 animated swing infinite">
           <span>Oferta!</span>
        </span>
        <a href="#" class="special-categ">Ofertas especiales</a>
        <span class="special-price">200,00 €</span>
        <del style="margin-top: -9px;">250,00 €</del>
        <a href="0#" class="special-add cd-add-to-cart js-cd-add-to-cart">+ Add to cart</a>
    </p>
</div>
```

Troubles getting the ID (so the value) of some elements inside this division (`div id="special"`) :
i want for example to get the ID of `<span id="pdctName">` and `<span class="special-price">`.

The element that triggers my function is 
`<a href="0#" class="special-add cd-add-to-cart js-cd-add-to-cart">+ Add to cart</a>`.

i tried `document.querySelector('#special span#pdctName').innerText`, it works only for **the first** occurence of this div, but i want to retrieve those elements for the **selected** division.

Comment: Are you using jQuery or pure JS

Answer (score 0):

Yes getElementById always give you first element. You have to find element using this object

Example is as follow

```js
var buttons=document.getElementsByClassName("js-cd-add-to-cart");
[].slice.call(buttons).forEach(x=>{
  x.addEventListener('click',function(obj){
    console.log(this.closest("#special").innerText);
    return false;
  }) 
})
```

```html
<div class="special" id="special">
    <a href="12v.html" class="special-link">
        <p class="special-img">
            <img src="img/25.png" alt="">
        </p>
        <h3><span id="pdctName">12x XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX</span></h3>
    </a>
    <p class="special-info">
        <span class="ribbon2 animated swing infinite">
           <span>Oferta1</span>
        </span>
        <a href="#" class="special-categ">Ofertas especiales1</a>
        <span class="special-price">300,00 €</span>
        <del style="margin-top: -9px;">450,00 €</del>
        <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="special-add cd-add-to-cart js-cd-add-to-cart">+ Add to cart</a>
    </p>
</div>
<div class="special" id="special">
    <a href="12v.html" class="special-link">
        <p class="special-img">
            <img src="img/25.png" alt="">
        </p>
        <h3><span id="pdctName">12v XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX</span></h3>
    </a>
    <p class="special-info">
        <span class="ribbon2 animated swing infinite">
           <span>Oferta1</span>
        </span>
        <a href="#" class="special-categ">Ofertas especiales</a>
        <span class="special-price">600,00 €</span>
        <del style="margin-top: -9px;">150,00 €</del>
        <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="special-add cd-add-to-cart js-cd-add-to-cart">+ Add to cart</a>
    </p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

First, you have to attach event on every add(+) button

Then call parent div element using `this.parentElement.parentElement`

Then get values using `querySelector`

```js
function addtocart(){
  event.preventDefault();
  var spanid = this.parentElement.parentElement.querySelector("a h3 span").id;
  var price = this.parentElement.parentElement.querySelectorAll("p span")[2].innerText;
  console.log(spanid);
  console.log(price);
}
[...document.querySelectorAll(".special-add")].forEach((btn)=>{
  btn.addEventListener("click",addtocart);
});
```

```html
<div class="special" id="special">
<a href="12v.html" class="special-link">
    <p class="special-img">
        <img src="img/25.png" alt="">
    </p>
    <h3><span id="pdctName">12v XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX</span></h3>
</a>
<p class="special-info">
    <span class="ribbon2 animated swing infinite">
       <span>Oferta!</span>
    </span>
    <a href="#" class="special-categ">Ofertas especiales</a>
    <span class="special-price">200,00 €</span>
    <del style="margin-top: -9px;">250,00 €</del>
    <a href="0#" class="special-add cd-add-to-cart js-cd-add-to-cart">+ Add to cart</a>
</p>
</div>
```

This is best practice when data is dynamically added to pages.

Answer (score 0):

I have a couple suggestions on how you could improve the structure of your `special` elements.

### Data

If you want to extract data from a HTML element, and you have multiple pieces of data to extract, then consider using a `form` with `input type="hidden"` elements in there. They will not be visible to the user and can hold information that will be easy for you to use.

In combination with the `FormData API` you can access all of the `input` values in your form and add them to your cart if you need to.

If you do use the form element than change the `<a class="special-add..` link to a button. I doesn't link anywhere anyway, so it probably should be a button.

### IDs

It seems that you have multiple `id` attributes with the same values on your page, assuming you have more than one special. If that is the case, remove them or make them totally unique.

It's also the reason why `getElementById` doesn't work properly. It always finds the **first** element with the matching id.

Check the example below. If you have any questions please let me know.

```js
function addSpecialToCart(event) {

  /**
   * Get all the inputs in the form.
   */
  const formData = new FormData(event.target);
  
  /**
   * Show all data in the current form.
   * Loop over the items in formData and
   * show the name and value of each input.
   */
  for (const [ name, value ] of formData) {
    console.log(name, value);
  }
  
  /**
   * Or get a single value by the name of the input.
   */
  const productName = formData.get('product-name');
  console.log(productName);
  
  event.preventDefault();
};

document.addEventListener('submit', addSpecialToCart);
```

```html
<div class="special">
  <form class="special-form">
    <input type="hidden" name="product-name" value="Product 1"/>
    <input type="hidden" name="product-category" value="Ofertas especiales1"/>
    <input type="hidden" name="special-price" value="150"/>
    <a href="12v.html" class="special-link">
      <p class="special-img">
        <img src="img/25.png" alt="">
      </p>
      <h3><span class="pdctName">Product 1</span></h3>
    </a>
    <p class="special-info">
      <span class="ribbon2 animated swing infinite">
               <span>Oferta1</span>
      </span>
      <a href="#" class="special-categ">Ofertas especiales1</a>
      <span class="special-price">150,00 €</span>
      <del style="margin-top: -9px;">250,00 €</del>
      <button type="submit" class="special-add cd-add-to-cart js-cd-add-to-cart">+ Add to cart</button>
    </p>
 </form>
</div>

<div class="special">
  <form class="special-form">
    <input type="hidden" name="product-name" value="Product 2"/>
    <input type="hidden" name="product-category" value="Ofertas especiales2"/>
    <input type="hidden" name="special-price" value="300"/>
    <a href="12v.html" class="special-link">
      <p class="special-img">
        <img src="img/25.png" alt="">
      </p>
      <h3><span class="pdctName">Product 2</span></h3>
    </a>
    <p class="special-info">
      <span class="ribbon2 animated swing infinite">
               <span>Oferta1</span>
      </span>
      <a href="#" class="special-categ">Ofertas especiales2</a>
      <span class="special-price">300,00 €</span>
      <del style="margin-top: -9px;">450,00 €</del>
      <button type="submit" class="special-add cd-add-to-cart js-cd-add-to-cart">+ Add to cart</button>
    </p>
 </form>
</div>

<div class="special">
  <form class="special-form">
    <input type="hidden" name="product-name" value="Product 3"/>
    <input type="hidden" name="product-category" value="Ofertas especiales3"/>
    <input type="hidden" name="special-price" value="1200"/>
    <a href="12v.html" class="special-link">
      <p class="special-img">
        <img src="img/25.png" alt="">
      </p>
      <h3><span class="pdctName">Product 3</span></h3>
    </a>
    <p class="special-info">
      <span class="ribbon2 animated swing infinite">
               <span>Oferta1</span>
      </span>
      <a href="#" class="special-categ">Ofertas especiales3</a>
      <span class="special-price">1200,00 €</span>
      <del style="margin-top: -9px;">1450,00 €</del>
      <button type="submit" class="special-add cd-add-to-cart js-cd-add-to-cart">+ Add to cart</button>
    </p>
 </form>
</div>
```